# Why array return value with array index value?

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [candi_id] => 1
            [2] => 
            [title] => 
            [3] => Lakshmanan
            [firstname] => Lakshmanan
            [4] => P
            [lastname] => P
            [5] => Male
            [gender] => Male
            [6] => Tamil
            [mothertongue] => Tamil
            [7] => 31-01-1990
            [dob] => 31-01-1990
            [8] => Hindu
            [religion] => Hindu
            [9] => O+
            [bloodgroup] => O+
            [10] => Single
            [marital_status] => Single
            [11] => Mettupalayam
            [native] => Mettupalayam
            [12] => Indian
            [nationality] => Indian
            [13] => Active
            [status] => Active
            [14] => 2016-11-04
            [cdate] => 2016-11-04
        )

)
```

I want to get only column value.but why i get array index with value?

Comment: Are you getting data from mysql DB with mysql functions?

Comment: yes sir i used mysql fetch array()

Comment: use this mysql_fetch_array ( $result ,MYSQL_ASSOC )

Comment: are u using mysqli or mysql???

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to say that `mysql` function is deprecated. So now onward use of `mysqli` or `PDO` is better for `mysql` `databse` functionalities.

Without any argument `mysql_fetch_array` function will output `DB` record in `index` and `column-name` both format.

To get data as `column-name` only you should have to pass second argument "`MYSQL_ASSOC`" in `mysql_fetch_array` function or instead you can use `mysql_fetch_assoc` function as well.

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_query);
```